# Kendo Grid Aggregation for Footer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to achieve showing the sum of a column as a footer. Following official Kendo UI demos, my code is as follows :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ORMIModel.Content.ContentPurchase.CheckoutListModel>()
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.ContentId).ClientTemplate("<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='RemoveFromCart(#=ContentId#)'>#=CategoryName#</a>").Width(50).Sortable(true);
    columns.Bound(p => p.CategoryName).Width(140).Sortable(true);
    columns.Bound(p => p.ModelYear).Width(100).Sortable(true);
    columns.Bound(p => p.PurchasePeriod).Width(100).Sortable(true);
    columns.Bound(p => p.PurchasePeriodCount).Width(50).Sortable(true);
    columns.Bound(p => p.FeeFormatted).Width(50).Sortable(true).ClientFooterTemplate("#=sum#");
})
.Sortable()
.ClientDetailTemplateId("detailTemplate")
.Events(v => v.DetailExpand("detailExpand"))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
            .Aggregates(v => { v.Add(p => p.Fee).Sum(); })
    .Read(read => read.Action("ListContentForCheckout", "Content"))                   
)
```

As it can be seen above, I'm properly defining the aggregate field, and applying it as #=sum# to my last column's clientFooterTemplate.

However, I'm getting an error as "Uncaught ReferenceError: sum is not defined "

My datasource has the Fee attribute aswell. Any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is caused by your column:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.FeeFormatted).Width(50).Sortable(true).ClientFooterTemplate("#=sum#");
```

is targeting the **FeeFormatted** property but the sum aggregate is processed against the **p.Fee** property.

try changing the column

```
    columns.Bound(p => p.FeeFormatted).Width(50).Sortable(true).ClientFooterTemplate("#=sum#");
```

to

```
    columns.Bound(p => p.Fee).Width(50).Sortable(true).ClientFooterTemplate("#=sum#");
```

to see if it works. then use the grid column .Format property to bring in the desired formatting of the Fee value

Comment: Hi Ancalagon, thanks for your response. I have changed as you suggested, and now It works. Didnt think I needed to exactly place the footer the the aggregate field. However there's another weird problem now, lets say I have only 1 row and It's fee value is 5.00. However my footer (sum of fee) shows 0 (zero). Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```html
 .Aggregates(aggregates =>
                            {
                                aggregates.Add(c => c.MrcPerUnit).Sum();

                            })

// it works with my own application
```